# jQuery's Flexigrid show/hide columns feature in the header

Tags: jquery, flexigrid

Here is my Flexigrid:

```
$("#grUser").flexigrid({
    url: 'someJSON.php'
    , dataType: 'json'
    , colModel : 
    [
        {display: '', name : 'Index', width :100, align: 'left'}
        , {display: '', name : 'Value', width : 100, align: 'left'}
    ]
    , title: 'Details'
    , width: 350
    , height: 200
    , singleSelect: true 
});
```

The show/hide columns feature in the header is really cool option, but **I want to specify on which column to be available**, and I am having trouble finding a good documentation about what are my options in specifying the colModel. Here

```
{display: '', name : 'Index', width :100, align: 'left'}
```

What else can we put in the definition of a column?

Additionally - what is your documentation source for Flexigrid?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Unfortunately, documentation for this isn't there and is thus very frustrating. You have to look at the source code and see what you can do.

Just add 'hide: true' as shown below. Setting hide to true, will hide a column.

```
{display: 'Row ID', name : 'id', width : 100, sortable : true, align: 'left', hide: true}
```

You can set the following attributes:
 - `display` (this is what is used for column headings)

- `name` (this is the database field name used for Ajax calls)
- `width`
- `height`
- `sortable`: true/false
- `align`: left/center/right
- `hide`: true/false
- `searchable`: true/false (only applicable if you have the search bar turned on)

Comment: +1, thanks for the answer. This is what I found myself, after all I ended with so changed/custom Flexigrid.js, that I can not even use it elsewhere... :)

Comment: Thanks for sharing code. I have updated code to not enable hide column from show/hide column list